# SWING's JToolbar separator orientation

Tags: swing, orientation, jtoolbar

I found a task which says that:

> SWING does not contain component which implements separator (vertical or horizontal) depending on toolbar orientation. By inheriting `JComponent`, make component which has that implementation, and take into assumption that its parent should always be `JToolbar` component.

Would someone mind explaining to me how separator does not depend on toolbar orientation? I thought that by specifying in `JToolbar` constructor how should orientation be made, I already do that. (I'm using addSeparator() method from `JToolbar` class, not `JSeparator`)

Comment: *"SWING does not contain component which implements separator (vertical or horizontal) depending on toolbar orientation."* Yes it does! Note also that it's Swing, not SWING. Start from the premise that whoever specified this task is a rank amateur, who does not know what they are talking about,

Comment: @AndrewThompson  ,,Start from the premise that whoever specified this task is a rank amateur, who does not know what they are talking about''. What do you mean by that, I am seriously asking, this is my university professor's question in the previous years (might be an older JDK version)?

Comment: Besides the incorrect case used for Swing, there is the (more important) part that the tool bar separator adapts flawlessly to wither horizontal or vertical toolbars. All it takes is a few lines of code to test & prove that, by the way.